# How to make an update sql in which add 1 to value existing, using App Inventor with FusionTables

Tags: sql-update, google-fusion-tables, app-inventor

I have the following table in FusionTables connected with my app in App Inventor:

[image]

I need to add 1 vote in my database every time that someone writes the **Name** of one of the participants and send it from the App.

All is functioning, but I can't make that sum occur.
My code with error is:

```
UPDATE my_table SET Vote= Vote + 1 WHERE RowID = 'tomar GlobalRowID'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't do math in updates with Fusion Tables SQL. You have to fetch the row, do the math, and then update it back. See [the documentation](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v2/sql-reference#updateRow) for details.